# Firestore: Is it possibile to have duplicate auto generated ID across different subcollection?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of Shop, every shop have a subcollection of item.
Item document has a property `isAvailable` which is a boolean.

Then, I need to put item in the user's shopping cart.
It's important to observe item `isAvailable` value to inform in real-time that an item is no longer available and auto-remove from all shopping cart.

So I decided to put in the Item object an array of user id and create a duplicated list of all objects at root level of db to simulate an observable shopping cart (I thought it's a good way to structure for this purpose, if you have bettere ideas just tell me).

My problem is: since I duplicate all the subcollections in a single collection and use the same document id, there may be duplicates in the final big collection, is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, auto-generate iDs are statistically unique with a good enough probability to consider it all the time. See [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html?m=1).

Also in firestore, the time-based calculation has been removed so the ids are not chronological anymore compared to the real-time database.

Regarding your data structure, I wouldn't recommend duplicating as one of the benefits of firestore is to avoid that, versus real-time database which in some cases you would need to do that.

Also avoid arrays as much as you can and use the object instead of as you can query them.

As I understand, you just want to make sure the items are available. I suggest you do a check when a user wants to proceed to checkout or anytime the page is refreshed and this way you ensure no unavailable product is purchased. That's it.

If you still have a problem, perhaps give me a snapshot of your data rather than explaining, something like 
ShopsCollection
    - itemDocument
       - isAvailable : true